# Package pgfkeys Error: I do not know the key '/tikz/y error plus index'

Tags: pgfplots, errors, matlab2tikz

I am having trouble compiling the attached mwe. I receive the following message: "Package pgfkeys Error: I do not know the key '/tikz/y error plus index' and I am going to ignore it. Perhaps you misspelled it." The tikz picture was created by matlab2tikz so I am surprised it doesn't compile. Can anyone please tell me what is wrong?

```
\documentclass[a4paper,titlepage,11pt]{article}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{positioning, arrows}
\usetikzlibrary{external}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[%
width=4.30216535433071in,
height=3.3931594488189in,
scale only axis,
xmin=0,
xmax=12,
xlabel={x},
ymin=9000,
ymax=17000,
ylabel={y}
]
\addplot [color=blue,only marks,mark=*,mark options={solid},forget plot]
 plot [error bars/.cd, y dir = both, y explicit]
 table[row sep=crcr, y error plus index=2, y error minus index=3]{1.84  16218   134.776481295696    134.776481295696\\
3.68    14575   127.048609378389    127.048609378389\\
5.52    13049   119.621537352246    119.621537352246\\
7.36    11775   113.088768071349    113.088768071349\\
9.2 10533   106.531395413076    106.531395413076\\
11.04   9374    100.152475255634    100.152475255634\\
};
\addplot [color=red,solid,forget plot]
  table[row sep=crcr]{1.84  16243.611047826\\
3.68    14567.6214518194\\
5.52    13064.55775989\\
7.36    11716.5777560882\\
9.2 10507.6801555369\\
11.04   9423.51466013115\\
};
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Welcome to TeX SE! Thanks for providing a complete example. That code works fine here, though. By the way, why are you loading `external` when you do not enable externalisation?

Comment: Asymmetric error bars have been added for `pgfplots 1.9` (current stable is 1.10). Maybe your version is outdated and does not contain the feature?

Comment: I have got to start typing faster.

Comment: I'm getting the same error when submitting to arXiv.  Does anyone know an elegant way to get around this without resorting to standalone pdfs?

Answer (score 4):

Your code work with TexLive 2014.

Here is the result

[image]